# System.getProperty(line.separator) error

Tags: java

I'm a java student and this example is from the textbook. The problem I'm having is line.separator isn't putting the record on the next line.  The result, at the bottom, is what it's doing.  It's putting the records on the same row.  The book shows the output the way it should be.  I copy and paste the code into Eclipse and Notepad and run it.  I get the same result both ways. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateEmployeesRandomFile {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Path file = Paths.get("C:\\EJava\\Employee.txt");

    String s = "000, ,00.00" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    final int RECSIZE = s.length();
    FileChannel fc = null;
    String delimiter = ",";
    String idString;
    int id;
    String name;
    String payRate;
    final String QUIT = "999";
    try {
        fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(file, CREATE, WRITE);
        System.out.print("Enter employee ID number >> ");
        idString = input.nextLine();
        while (!(idString.equals(QUIT))) {
            id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
            System.out.print("Enter name for employee #" + id + " >> ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter pay rate >> ");
            payRate = input.nextLine();
            s = idString + delimiter + name + delimiter + payRate
                    + System.getProperty("line.separator");
            byte[] data = s.getBytes();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            fc.position(id * RECSIZE);
            fc.write(buffer);
            System.out.print("Enter next ID number or " + QUIT
                    + " to quit >> ");
            idString = input.nextLine();
        }
        fc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error message: " + e);
    }
}
```

}

result:
 000, ,00.00
001,Greg Look002,John Smit003,Fred Flint,2541.02

000,  ,00.00
000,  ,00.00
etc

Answer (score 0):

try change this line.

```
fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(file, CREATE, WRITE);
```

to

```
fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(file, READ, WRITE);
```

Comment: It is OS dependent. The line separator is there; perhaps the problem is with the program you're using to view the text: Windows Notepad. Every other program in the world will accept any of the three most common line separators: "\n" (linefeed only), "\r" (carriage-return only), or "\r\n" (carriage-return + linefeed). But Notepad only recognizes "\r\n", the traditional line separator for DOS/Windows systems. Try use something other than Notepad to view the text and see if it works.

Comment: Do you use Java jdK 7 or 8? If you have Java 8, change it to System.lineSeparator() and see if it works. Another way to debug is just replace it with OS line separator, Windows ("\r\n") and others ("\n") in your string and see if it shows up.

Comment: I tried those and it's still happening.  I'm starting to think it's not the line.separator and more with these 4 lines of code:   byte[] data = s.getBytes();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            fc.position(id * RECSIZE);
            fc.write(buffer);

Comment: Very likely. Try adding System.out.print(s); before byte[] data = s.getBytes() and see if the string was correctly shown in the console.

Comment: The string is correctly shown, they still won't display properly in the list.